# Dynamic populating dropdown using jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to dynamically populat the drop down list based on the selected value of first list.

NOTE: Both dropdowns are multiple selection dropdown:

This is the code for my dropdowns:

```
<select id="dis" name="dis[]" onChange="AjaxFunction();" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow" multiple  title="Select a City or Division">
  // my discrictes goes here  
</select>

<select id="zone" name="zone[]" class="form-control  show-menu-arrow" multiple  title="Choose Educational Zone" ></select>
```

To do this I found `AjaxFunction()` javascript function. And its as below:

```
function AjaxFunction(){
  var httpxml;
  try {
    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {
    // Internet Explorer
    try {
      httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  function stateck() {
    if(httpxml.readyState==4) {
      var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
      // Before adding new we must remove previously loaded elements
      for(j=document.getElementById('s2').length-1;j>=0;j--) {
        document.getElementById('s2').remove(j);
      }

      for (i=0;i<myarray.data.length;i++) {
        var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
        optn.text = myarray.data[i].name_si;
        optn.value = myarray.data[i].zone_id;  
        document.getElementById('s2').options.add(optn);
      } 
    }
  }

  var str='';
  var s1ar=document.getElementById('s1');
  for (i=0;i< s1ar.length;i++) { 
    if(s1ar[i].selected) {
      str += s1ar[i].value + ','; 
    }
  } 
  //alert (s1ar);

  var str=str.slice(0,str.length -1); // remove the last coma from string
  //alert(str);

  //alert(str);
  var url="../includes/dropdown-zones.php";

  url=url+"?dis_id="+str;
  url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
  //alert(url);
  httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
  httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
  //httpxml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  httpxml.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

  httpxml.send(null);
}
```

My question is, now I need to convert above function to jquery, because I am looking for a jQuery/Ajax solution for this:

This is how I tried it using jQuery:

```
$('#dis').on('change',function() {
  var str='';
  var s1ar=document.getElementById('dis');
  for (i=0;i< s1ar.length;i++) { 
    if(s1ar[i].selected) {
      str += s1ar[i].value + ','; 
    }
  } 

  var str=str.slice(0,str.length -1);
  var url="../includes/dropdown-zones.php";
      url=url+"?dis_id="+str;
      url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url, 
    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#zone').empty();
      $('#zone').append("<option value=''>- Select Zone-</option>");
      $.each(data, function(i,item){
        var selecting; 
        if (selected === data[i].id) {
          selecting = ' selected="selected"'; 
        } else {
          selecting = '';
        }
        $('#zone').append('<option '+selecting+' value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</optoin>');
      });
    }, 
    complete: function() {}
  }); 
});
```

But is not working for me. Can anybody help me out to figure this out?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine, I am getting error with "selected" is undefined

You can see `if(selected === data[i].id)` here "selected" variable is not assigned to selected value from first dropdown.

also you need to remove `onChange="AjaxFunction();"` from first dropdown because now your are using jQuery

Check below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#dis').on('change',function() {
  
   var str='';
   var s1ar=document.getElementById('dis');
   for (i=0;i< s1ar.length;i++) { 
  if(s1ar[i].selected) {
    str += s1ar[i].value + ','; 
  }
   }
   
   var str=str.slice(0,str.length -1);
   var url="dropdown-zones.php";
    url=url+"?dis_id="+str;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();

   $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url, 
  contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $('#zone').empty();
    $('#zone').append("<option value=''>- Select Zone-</option>");
    $.each(data, function(i,item){
   var selecting=''; 
   if ($('#dis').val().findIndex(x => x==data[i].id)>=0) {
     selecting = ' selected="selected"'; 
   } else {
     selecting = '';
   }
   $('#zone').append('<option '+selecting+' value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</optoin>');
    });
  }, 
  complete: function() {}
   }); 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dis" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow" multiple  title="Select a City or Division">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>

<select id="zone" class="form-control  show-menu-arrow" multiple  title="Choose Educational Zone" ></select>
```

The result is some like this:
[image]

jSon file value is :

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "New"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Open"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Close"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it dosen't populating second dropdown. That is my main problem

Comment: Make sure "dropdown-zones.php" is returning value. I have tested this code working, also update above answer with screenshot and json file result.